# Using Breez.js with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, breeze

This is more of an exploration question.
We have been using breeze.js in our projects for a while and have been quite satisfied with it; it ties nicely into concepts we already know and use (change tracking, metadata, backend agnostic...)

Now we are evaluating the possibility to move our front-end from backbone/marionette/knockout stack to ember.js (which seems to be more of a complete framework than a "pick-only-what-you-need" approach in backbone). We are exploring to possibility to keep using breeze.js as our data management layer on the client-front.

But how can the integration of models returned from the server (server stack: node.js + mongoDB) be done with models defined by ember.js?

A typical ember model definition could be:

```
var Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    Property1: 'foo',
    Property2: 'bar'
});
```

where you can see the extension "Ember.Object.**extend**"

Breeze.js upon receiving data from server attach a AspectEntity to them (and if Knockout is defined, wrap properties in observables ). How could returned objects somehow be "transformed" into ember.js objects?

Maybe the way we approach this problem and the way we think about this integration is totally wrong or that we should entirely reject this "ember-breeze" combo. From google search we have not found cases where breeze is used with ember.js or some guidance. That is why we come to the stackoverflow community: is it possible? what are the possible pitfalls to look ahead?

Comment: you can create a new person with `Person.create(someJson)` for example, if the attribute names match.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be much in the way of existing solutions. The Breeze.js [User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions?query=ember) has some 2-year-old issues that never got much traction; support from that library does not seem to be imminent.

I would recommend exploring Ember-Data as your data management layer. It supports many (if not all) of the concepts you mentioned, and it's the default recommended data library for Ember applications.

That said, as far as trying to make Breeze.js work, you could probably take the objects returned from Breeze and turn them into Ember.Objects using Ember.Object.create, but you'd have to build a layer between Breeze and Ember that essentially serializes between Breeze objects and Ember objects in both directions.